# Autoware : Unable to complete the demo

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

- Autoware version : 1.12.0
- ROS Version : Melodic
- Autoware installed from Docker
- Docker version 19.03.2, build 6a30dfc

I am trying to run the demo of autoware  here : https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/wikis/ROSBAG-Demo

But I am experiencing a lot of problems.

First of all, I download the files, create a `.autoware` in my personal home and extract the files there.

I start autoware by running the `run.sh` file, I am now connected with the `autoware` user 'in' the docker container.

But then the first instruction is to move to the directory `autoware.ai` which doesn't exist !

The right folder seems to be

> /home/autoware/Autoware

Then I source the setup.bash file.

I start the runtime manager with

> roslaunch runtime_manager runtime_manager.launch

Then I move to the `simulation` tab and try to load the bag file from `~/.autoware` but the folder doesn't contain my files...

I am truly lost, and I can't see what I did wrong. Thanks for the help !

---

[Edit] I made it working by using `~/Autoware` instead of `~/autoware.ai` (In the docker machine)

Then I copied the `~/.autoware` from the host to the docker machine and It's fine.

Do you think I did something wrong or the documentation maybe deserves a pull request ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/334474/autoware-:-unable-to-complete-the-demo/) by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 196 on 2019-10-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It does look like the demo instructions need some updating. I will put that on my list and report back when they are updated. We are in the middle of the 1.13.0 release process right now so it may take a little while.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2019-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0